# How to identify dotted line on a text?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am working on automating a web application using Selenium with Ruby.
There is a text which displays a dotted line while hovering over it.

The html looks something like this for the text:

```
<span class="app-header"
      style="padding-top: 3px;"
      data-infobox-type="department"
      tabindex="-1">ABC </span>
```

How can i verify if the dotted line appears on hovering over the text 'ABC'?

Thanks!

Comment: You could check if the element has the appropriate [`css_value`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#css_value-instance_method)

Comment: If element change its appearance it means that `onmouseover` event called to place new element over initial one. So you just need to check if new element (dotted line) currently (in testing moment) displayed. You should define new element's `HTML` code

Comment: As far as I know you cannot check actual pixels using Capybara and if so you wouldn't easily know the x,y co-ordinate to look at. The best you can do is check for the style/element which causes the dotted line.